# Prove that $AB\cdot CD\geq 2S$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Question:

> Let $M$ be the centroid of triangle $ABC$. $D$ is a point on the line passing through $A$ and parallel to $BC$ such that $\angle CMD=90^\circ$. Let $S=[AMCD]$. Prove that $AB\cdot CD\geq2S$.

[image: Graph]

This question was the last question from a mock exam a few days ago. To clarify, this exam is contest-style and for 7-8th graders.

My approach: I immediately noticed that $2S=AC\cdot MD\sin\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between $AC$ and $MD$. Hence, it suffices to prove that $AB\cdot CD\geq AC\cdot MD$, since $\sin\alpha\leq1$. This is then equivalent to $\dfrac{AB}{AC}\geq\dfrac{DM}{DC}$. However, I am not sure how do approach the problem from here. Any help on solving this using (preferably) *synthetic geometry* will be appreciated!

Comment: IraeVid, it is impossible to prove that $\,AB\cdot CD\geq AC\cdot MD\,$ because in some cases it results that $AB\cdot CD< AC\cdot MD\,.$ The inequality $\,AB\cdot CD\geq 2S\,$ cannot be improved, otherwise in some cases it would not be true.

Comment: @Angelo Thanks, but do you have any other ideas? I need this question rather urgently as there is another test tomorrow for me.

Comment: IraeVid, I am trying to solve your problem, but I need time, indeed it is not so easy for me.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem of a new shape, do we have the name of the author?! +1

Comment: @IraeVid, I have found an analytic geometry solution for your problem by using a coordinate system. Are you interested in it ? Or do you want only synthetic geometry solutions ?

Comment: Well, since the answers given are all rather complicated, I am interested to see your solution @Angelo. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IraeVid, could you ask your profesor to give you a synthetic geometry solution? Indeed I am very interested in it since I could not find one, but only I found an analytic geometry solution by using a coordinate system.

Comment: @IraeVid, my solution contains a lot of calculations, indeed first I got the coordinates of $M$ and $D$ as functions of the coordinates $(x,y)$ of $A$, then I calculated $AB\!\cdot\!CD$ and $S$ and finally I proved algebraically that $AB\!\cdot\!CD\geqslant2S\,.\,$ Do you mind if my solution contains a lot of algebraic calculations?

Comment: @IraeVid, could you read my answer? What do you think about it? Are there too many algebraic calculations? Tell me if you like my proof.

Comment: @Angelo Your solution is alright, I can understand it, but I'm still looking for a synthetic solution. Besides, my professor/teacher did not share the solution and left it to us as a challenge.

Comment: @IraeVid, I think there exists a short elegant solution, but unfortunately I have not been able to find it. If in the future your teacher share the solution, will you write it here ? I hope yes because I am very interested in it.

Comment: I have a problem with the explicit question addressed to the community. This is a Q+A site, and it is always good to have **explicitly** a question. (This would make the comments to the answers easier to address, it is the issue i have right now.) I understand the question from the mock exam. (At this point, please give more details on this occasion. Which is the level, the country, what are the allowed instruments, is it an oral exam, and the answer should be delivered by genius, or people go home and elaborate...) *Please state a clear question.* Is only a **synthetic** solution of interest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $N$ be the midpoint of $CD$. Note that $MN=\frac 12 CD$ as $\angle CMD=90^\circ$. Let $MN$ intersect $AB$ at $X$. Note that
$$AB \cdot CD = 2AB\cdot MN \ge 2 AB \cdot MN \cdot \sin \angle AXN = 4[AMBN]$$
and it remains to show that $2[AMBN]=[AMCD]$. But this is very easy: we have
$$[AMBN]=[ABN]-[ABM]=\frac 12[ABCD]-\frac13 [ABC]$$
and
$$[AMCD]=[ABCD]-[ABCM]=[ABCD]-\frac 23 [ABC].$$
Done!

[image]

**Addendum.** There are other possible configurations of points. For instance, it may happen that points $A$ and $D$ lie on different halfplanes determined by $CM$. Similar ideas work: as before we have $AB \cdot CD \ge 4[AMBN]$. Note that $[ABN]=[ABD]−[ANBD]=[ACBN]−[ACB]$, so taking the average and using $[ANBD]=[ACBN]$ we get
$$[ABN]=\frac 12 \Big([ABD]−[ANBD]+[ACBN]−[ACB]\Big)=\frac 12 \Big([ABD]−[ACB]\Big).$$
Therefore
$$[AMBN]=[ABN]+[AMB]=\frac 12\Big([ABD] - [ACB]\Big) + \frac 13[ACB] = \frac 12 [ABD]-\frac 16 [ACB].$$
and
$$[AMCD]=[ACD]-[ACM]=[ABD]-\frac 13[ACB],$$
which shows that $2[AMBN]=[AMCD]$.

[image]

Yet another configuration: points $A$ and $D$ lie on the same halfplane determined by $CM$ and segments $CD$, $AM$ intersect. Then we have simply
$$AB \cdot CD \ge 2[ACBD] > 2[ACMD].$$

[image]

Comment: Congratulations!!! Your proof is the only one that gives us the geometric condition ($MN\!\perp\!AB$) for which $AB\!\cdot\!CD=2S$.

Comment: Congratulations for your brilliant solution!!! I have already upvoted your answer.

Comment: Very nice and simple solution! [+1]

Comment: Thank you very much for your marvelous answer, I like it so much.

Answer (score 2):

Using vectors

Calling

$$
A=(x_a,y_a), B=(0,0), C=(x_c,0), D = (x_d,y_a)
$$

we have

$$
M = \frac 13(A+B+C)\\
S = \frac 12\|\frac{4}{3} y_a \left(x_a -\frac{1}{3} (x_a+x_c)\right)+\frac{1}{3} y_a \left(\frac{x_a+x_c}{3}-x_c\right)+2 y_a(x_d-x_a)+y_a (x_c-x_d)\|
$$

now from $\|D-M\|^2+\|C-M\|^2=\|D-C\|^2$ we obtain

$$
y_a^2=\frac 12\left(x_a-2x_c\right)\left(x_a+x_c-3x_d\right)\ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
$$

and from the condition

$$
\|A-B\|^2\|C-D\|^2\ge 4 S^2 \Rightarrow(x_a^2+y_a^2)\left(y_a^2+(x_c-x_d)^2\right)\ge \frac 19(x_c+3(x_d-x_a))^2y_a^2
$$

Using $(*)$ we got

$$
\left(3x_a^2+2x_c(x_c-3x_d)-x_a(x_c+3x_d)\right)^2\ge 0
$$

meaning that the statement it is true.

Comment: If $x_a>x_d$, you do not get the correct area of the convex quadrilateral $ADMC$ but you get the area of $ADP\cup MCP$ where $P$ is the intersection point of the diagonals $AM$ and $CD$. See [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHxjk.png). For that reason, I considered two cases in my answer.

Comment: @Angelo It seems that always $x_a < x_d$.

Comment: No, it could be that $x_a>x_d$. Look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHxjk.png).

Comment: Really you are right! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: Particular case: suppose $CM=\frac{BC}2$, We construct right triangle CDC', such that $DC'=AB$ . We have:

$S_{DC"C}= (C'D=AB)\cdot CD$

Now we reflect MC  and D about AM , the result is hexagon  AG'C'MCD. We have:

$S_{AG'C'MCD}=2S_{CDAM}$

We connect C to C'. In hexagon $AG'C'MCD$ we delete portion DAG'C' and added portion MC'C and get triangle DC'C.  Now we have to show that:

$S_{AG'C'D}<S_{MC'C}$

In this case:

$2S_{ADCM}<S_{DC'C}=(DC'=AB)\cdot DC$

[image]

In this figure we see:

$S_{AG'CD}\approx S_{CIHD'''M'_1M}<S_{MCC'}$

Comment: Sirous, there is a typo indeed you wrote $$S_{DFC}= (FD=AB)\cdot AC$$ instead of $$S_{DFC}= \dfrac12(FD=AB)\cdot CD\,.$$ Moreover, could you explain why $S_{ACM}<S_{CDM}\Rightarrow S_{ADCM}<2S_{CDM}$ ?

Comment: @Angelo, Thanks for correcting me. The reason for $S_{ACM}<S_{CDM}$ is obvious from figure; FC is diameter of circle passing c, d and F, where CG can be considered as it's chord.

Comment: Sirous, I did not ask you why $S_{ACM}<S_{CDM}$, but I asked you why $S_{ACM}<S_{CDM}$ implies $S_{ADCM}<2S_{CDM}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for isosceles ABC:**

**I.** With $M$ centroid, $AD\parallel BC$, and $DM\perp MC$, let $\triangle ABC$ be isosceles with $AB=AC>BC$, and such that $CD\perp BC$. This occurs when semi-base $CG$ is the mean proportional between $GM$ and $MA$, i.e.$$\frac{GM}{CG}=\frac{CG}{MA}$$whence $$AB>GM+MA=AG>2CG=BC$$Thus, since $AM=2MG$, $ABC$ is the isosceles triangle in which$$\frac{altitide}{base}=\frac{3}{2\sqrt 2}$$From $C$ make $CK=BF$ and complete rectangle $CKND$. Since $AB>BC$, and $F$ and $G$ are midpoints of $AB$ and $BC$, then$$CK>CG=AD$$and$$CKND>ADCM$$[image: isosceles special case]And since$$CKND=BF\cdot CD=\frac{1}{2}AB\cdot CD$$then$$AB\cdot CD>2ADCM$$

**II.** Now, keeping $BC$ fixed, suppose altitude $AG$ increased as in the next figure.

With $CK=BF$ as before, construct rectangle $CKND$ whose side $KN$ intersects $AG$ , $AD$ at $L$, $J$, respectively, forming$$\triangle AJL\sim\triangle NJD$$Since $ND=AF$, and $AF>AL$ (proof?), then in area$$\triangle NJD>\triangle AJL$$
[image: increasing altitude AG]
and thus the triangle by which rectangle $CKND$ exceeds quadrilateral $ADCM$ is greater than the triangle by which $ADCM$ exceeds $CKND$.

And $CKND$ further exceeds $ADCM$ by concave quadrilateral $CKLM$.

Therefore, $CKND>ADCM$, and$$AB\cdot CD>2ADCM$$**Note:** As $AG$ increases, $AL$ and $ND$ converge toward equality, and area $CKLM$ converges to zero, so that in the limit$$AB\cdot CD=2ADCM$$

**III.** Returning to the first case, and keeping $BC$ fixed, if instead of increasing we diminish altitude $AG$, as in the next figure, since right triangles $AJD$, $NJL$ are similar, and $\triangle JNL>\triangle JAD$ (proof?), then $CKND$ exceeds $ADCM$ in area by$$\triangle JNL-\triangle JAD+CKLM$$and again$$AB\cdot CD>2ADCM$$
[image: diminishing altitude AG]
**Note:** Unlike the previous case, in which triangles $NJD$ and $AJL$ converge to equality as $AG$ increases, here$$\lim_{AG \to 0}{\frac{\triangle AJD}{\triangle NJL} \to 0}$$as both triangles vanish, while quadrilateral $MCKL$ approaches congruence with rectangle $CKND$.

Thus it seems$$\lim_{AG \to 0}{\frac{ADCM}{CKND} \to 0}$$
and the limiting value of $CKND$ is $$\lim_{AG \to 0}{\frac{AB}{2}\cdot {CD}}=\frac{CG^2}{2}$$

**Conclusion:** In general then, for isosceles $\triangle ABC$ $$AB\cdot CD\ge 2ADCM$$but it seems$$AB\cdot CD=2ADCM$$only at the limit in the second case, as $AG\to\infty$.

Comment: Is this an argumentation in a special case? If yes, please start the answer with a clear statement. It is simpler for readers (like me) in hurry, that see nine votes on a question. The information would help me to decide to validate a proof and upvote, or to start my own.

Comment: @dan_fulea, ok, I've tried to clarify the scope of the proof by editing the opening line.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A',B',C'$ be the mid points of the sides. Let $C''$ be the reflection of $C$ w.r.t. $C'$. (So $C''BCA$ is a parallelogram.)

The points so far are introduced in the order $A,B,C;A',B',C';M;C'',D$.

It is useful to change this "unnatural", order and moreover use only the following points in the following order:
$$
C,C'';M,C';D;A\ .
$$
Here $C,C''$ are arbitrary. Construct $C''$, the mid point of $CC'$, and $M$  on $CC'C''$ with $CM:CC''=1:3$. Consider now an arbitrary point $D$ on the perpendicular on $CMC'C''$ in $M$. Then finally $A$ is a free point on $C''D$.

We may want to remove $B$ from the picture, and use instead of $AB$ the value $2AC'$. See the first picture below for an orientation.
We have some cases, that are best described by pictures, separated below by horizontal lines:

---

$\bbox[beige]{\ (1)\ }$

[image: MSE problem 4743208]

In this case the point $D$ is between $A$ and $C''$.
In particular, the projection of $A$ on the line $MC$ is on the half-line $[MC$, $C'$ is on the "other" half-line from $M$, and thus $AM<MC'$. We can conclude:
$$
2[ADMC]\le AM\cdot CD < AC'\cdot CD=\frac 12 AB\cdot CD\ .
$$
Below we may and do assume that $A$ is on the half-line $DC''$.

---

$\bbox[beige]{\ (2)\ }$

Let $C^\perp$ be the projection of $C'$ on $DAC''$. We consider now the case when $A$ is between $D$ and $C^\perp$.

[image: MSE problem 4743208 second picture]

Or if we remove all the unuseful stuff, and denote by $x,h$ the length of the segments $MC'$ and $MD$:

[image: MSE problem 4743208 third picture]

We can compute easily in the above picture
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{[C''C'C^\perp]}{[C''MD]}
&=\left(\frac{C'C''}{C'D}\right)^2
=\frac{9x^2}{h^2 +16x^2}\ ,
\\
[C''C'C^\perp] &= \frac{9x^2}{h^2 +16x^2}\cdot 2xh\ ,\\
[C''MC^\perp] &= \frac 43[C''C'C^\perp]=\frac{12x^2}{h^2 +16x^2}\cdot 2xh\ ,\\
[C^\perp MCD] &= [C''CD] - [C''MC^\perp]
= 3xh - \frac{8x^2}{h^2 +16x^2}\cdot 3xh
= 3xh \cdot \frac{h^2 + 8x^2}{h^2 +16x^2}
\ ,\\
C'C^\perp &= h\cdot \frac{3x}{\sqrt{h^2+16x^2}}\ ,\\
CD &= \sqrt{h^2 + 4x^2}\ ,\\
C'C^\perp \cdot CD &= 3xh\cdot \frac{\sqrt{h^2 + 4x^2}}{\sqrt{h^2+16x^2}}\ ,
\\[4mm]
\left(\frac{2\; C'C^\perp\cdot CD}{2[C^\perp MCD]}\right)^2
&
= \frac{h^2+4x^2}{h^2+16x^2}\cdot\frac{(h^2+16x^2)^2}{(h^2+8x^2)^2}
= \frac{(h^2+4x^2)(h^2+16x^2)}{(h^2+8x^2)^2}
\\
&>1\ .\qquad \text{ From here we obtain:}
\\[4mm]
2\; C'C^\perp\cdot CD
&>2[C^\perp MCD]\ ,\qquad\text{ and now finally:} \\[4mm]
AB\cdot CD &= 2\; AC'\cdot CD\\
&>2\; C'C^\perp\cdot CD\\
&>2[C^\perp MCD]\\
&>2[A MCD]\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

$\bbox[beige]{\ (3)\ }$

The case $A$ in the half-line $[C^\perp C''$ is the remained case:

[image: MSE 4743208]

Let us denote by $y$ the length of $AC^\perp$. Then the area
$[AMCD]$ is the area of the triangle $[AMC^\perp]$ plus the already computed area $[C^\perp MCD]$. Note that $A$ may lie beyond $C''$, then $AMCD$ is no longer convex, but also in this case the relation is valid.

We then compute:

$$
\begin{aligned}{}
[AMCD] &=
[AMC^\perp] + [C^\perp MCD]
=\frac y{C''D}{[C''MD]} + [C^\perp MCD]
\\
&=\frac y{\sqrt{h^2 +16x^2}}\cdot 2xh + 3xh \cdot \frac{h^2 + 8x^2}{h^2 +16x^2}
\\
&=\frac{xh}{h^2 +16 x^2}\left( \ 2y\sqrt{h^2+16x^2}+ 3(h^2+8x^2)\ \right)\ ,
\\[3mm]
AB^2 &=4AC'{}^2 =4(y^2+C'C^\perp{}^2)
=4\left(y^2 + h^2\cdot\frac {9x^2}{h^2+16x^2}\right)\ ,
\\
(AB\cdot CD)^2 
&=
4\left( y^2 + h^2\cdot\frac {9x^2}{h^2+16x^2}\right)(h^2+4x^2)\ ,
\\[4mm]
\left(
\frac{AB\cdot CD}{2[AMCD]}
\right)^2
&=
\frac{(AB\cdot CD)^2}{4[AMCD]^2}
\\
&=
\frac
{(16x^2y^2 + 9h^2x^2 + h^2y^2)(h^2+4x^2)\ /\ (h^2+16x^2)}
{x^2h^2 \left( \ 2y\sqrt{h^2+16x^2}+ 3(h^2+8x^2)\ \right)^2\ /\ (h^2+16x^2)^2} 
\\
&=
\frac
{(16x^2y^2 + 9h^2x^2 + h^2y^2)\; (h^2+4x^2)\;(h^2+16x^2)}
{x^2h^2 \left( \ 2y\sqrt{h^2+16x^2}+ 3(h^2+8x^2)\ \right)^2} 
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We want to show that the last expression is $\ge 1$. So consider the numerator of
$\displaystyle 
\left(
\frac{AB\cdot CD}{2[AMCD]}
\right)^2
-1$ as a function of $y$ of degree two,
explicitly
$$
Ay^2 +By +C
=
(16x^2y^2 + 9h^2x^2 + h^2y^2)\; (h^2+4x^2)\;(h^2+16x^2)\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad
-
x^2h^2 \left( \ 2y\sqrt{h^2+16x^2}+ 3(h^2+8x^2)\ \right)^2\ .
$$
Then we isolate
$A,B,C$, and compute
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &=
(h^2+4x^2)\;(h^2+16x^2)^2
-
4x^2h^2 (h^2+16x^2)^2
\\
&=  (h^2+16x^2) (h^2+8x^2)^2
\ ,\\
B &= - x^2h^2 \cdot 4\sqrt{h^2+16x^2}\cdot 3(h^2+8x^2)
\ ,\\
C&= 9x^2h^2\; (h^2+4x^2)\;(h^2+16x^2)
-
x^2h^2 \cdot 9(h^2+8x^2)^2
\\
&=36 x^4 h^4
\ ,\\
B^2 - 4AC &= 0\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
which means that
$$
Ay^2+By+C= \Big(\ (h^2+8x^2)\sqrt{h^2+16x^2}\; y - 6x^2h^2\ \Big)^2
\ge 0
$$
makes indeed the needed quantity also non-negative.

$\square$

---

*Final notes:*
The value of $y$ leading to an equality is
$$
y^* = \frac{6x^2h^2}{(h^2+8x^2)\sqrt{h^2+16x^2}}\ ,
$$
and i could not see a natural argument producing this quantity.
In the expression there are of course as factors
the lengths of segments like the obvious
$h$ and some multiples of $x$, and the slightly less obvious
$C''D$.
I could not see how to move using similarities the segment $CD$ from its direction to one on the line $DC''$.

It is late here in a hard day's night, so i have to submit here, possibly come back to this point if there is still something to say.

Regarding the way the solution was typed, yes, the first two cases could have been also compressed to fit inside the third and last case, but in conditions of an olympiad i would have lost a lot of points, so it is safe for the sake of didactics and clearness to draw more and type more...

Above, synthetic geometry was used as far as possible,
and because i could not see any geometric sense for the ingredients of the inequality to be shown, i considered it as a geometric inequality. It was parametrized geometrically. We can solve it algebraically and possibly hide this solution if it give geometrical insight, but it did not. So the last algebraic step remained. In fact, initially i wanted to get one/any solution by using barycentric coordinated. (Because, as a speculation, an inequality of the same shape (may) should happen for all fixed constant barycentrics - the problem uses $M=[1:1:1]$. And because most of the solution can be recovered in this framework.) But the explicit wish of a *synthetic* approach was leading to the above. Still, this may be a special instance of a more general inequality.

Comment: Dan_fulea, I have found out that if the coordinates of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $A(x,y)$, $B(0,0)$ and $C(1,0)$, then $$AB\!\cdot\!CD=2S\iff\begin{cases}x^3+(x+2)y^2-4x^2+4x=0\\-2<x<0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad.\end{cases}$$Can you see a geometric sense in it ?

Comment: @Angelo For the first question, i am not using cartesian coordinates, instead i have tried to go as long as possible with geometrical insight. At some point, parameters **but not coordinates** were added. These parameters have easy explanation in terms of the triangle $\Delta ABC$ we start with, at least the first two $x=CM/2$ and $h=DM$.  Later on, the parameter $y$ fixing the position of $A$ on $DC''$ was introduced. The proof of the inequality is given in full terms for the case of a *negative* $y$, these are the first two cases. But for $y>0$ i need algebra. Expressing your $x,y$ as...

Comment: @Angelo ... as functions of my parameters $x,h,y$ is not an easy task. In my world, the equation to be solved is not of degree three in any of $x,y,h$. The choice of my parameters $x,h,y$ is not a random one, is not the first one, and i adapted after long computations. The choice i typed was the best for geometric purposes, i hoped to have an explanation for the point of equality, obtained e.g. in a geogebra plane by doing all constructions with intersections of (rather easy) lines and circles. I have the point $A^*$ so in a sketchpad, now i was looking which segments, circles, ... are

Comment: @Angelo ... are related to this point $A^*$. This is no longer part of the problem, but part of the OP wish to have everything in a synthetical approach. This problem is harder. Why? Simply because (i suppose) the author of the problem had some other insight, and she or he is hiding it. We are here without any idea about the cited "mock exam", about its level, about supplementary information, maybe parts of the problem are missing, maybe parallel questions or other questions are related... Anyways, i need time, i do not have it now.

Comment: @Angelo Regarding the second question, **yes**, i also cover the case of a "huge " $y$, that places $A$ beyond $C''$, it is the place where i mentioned that the quadrilateral $AMCD$ is no longer convex, and that its area is computed by the same formula, sum of areas of two (unoriented) triangles, $[AMD]$ plus $[CMD]$. This sum is minimized in the solution, and the point realizing the minimal value is described as good as i could do it.

Comment: @Angelo In my approach i am starting with $C,M,C''$. Then i take $D$ on the perpendicular line on $M$ on $CM$.  Then other points (one of them being $A$) are coming later in the game. There is no left and right when $D$ is invented. The order of inventing the points is changed at step $(2)$ explicitly, this is the reason for having two pictures in there. Please read. The proof is a full proof. I am slowly at the point of deleting it.

Comment: @Angelo Case (3) when $y$ is bigger than the length of the segment $C^\perp C''$. In some of the above comments is the place with "no longer convex" and "huge $y$" case.

Comment: Dan_fulea, you are absolutely right. There is just a typo in your proof in fact in the second case you wrote$$\frac{[C''C'C^\perp]}{[C''MD]}
=\left(\frac{C'C''}{C'D}\right)^2$$instead of $$\frac{[C''C'C^\perp]}{[C''MD]}
=\left(\frac{C'C''}{\color{red}{C'’}D}\right)^2\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

> Let $M$ be the centroid of triangle $ABC$. $D$ is a point on the line passing through $A$ and parallel to $BC$ such that $\,\angle CMD=90\unicode{176}.\,$ Let $\,S=[AMCD]\,.$
> Prove that $\,AB\cdot CD\geqslant2S\,.$

[image]

**Proof :**

Without loss of generality, we can suppose that the coordinates of the vertices of the triangle $ABC$ are :
$A(x,y)\,,\,$ where $\,y>0\,,\;$ $B(0,0)\,,\,$ $C(1,0)\,.$

Consequently, the coordinates of the centroid $M$ are :
$M\left(\dfrac{x+1}3,\dfrac y3\right).$

The equation of the line $r$ passing through $M$ and perpendicular to the segment $CM$ is :

$r)\;\;\;Y=\dfrac{2-x}y\left(X-\dfrac{x+1}3\right)+\dfrac y3$

whereas the equation of the line $s$ passing through $A$ and parallel to $BC$ is the following one :

$s)\;\;\;Y=y\;.$

Since $\,r\bigcap s\equiv D\,,\,$ the lines $r$ and $s$ are not parallel, hence it results that $\;2-x\neq0\;\;\;\color{blue}{(1)}\;,\;$ moreover the coordinates of the point $D$ are :

$D\left(\dfrac{2+x+2y^2-x^2}{3(2-x)},y\right).$

The lengths of the segments $AB$ and $CD$ are :

$AB=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\;\;,$

$\begin{align}CD&=\sqrt{\left[\dfrac{2y^2-(2-x)^2}{3(2-x)}\right]^2\!\!+y^2}=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac1{3|2-x|}\sqrt{\left[2y^2\!-(2-x)^2\right]^2\!+9y^2(2-x)^2}=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac1{3|2-x|}\sqrt{\left[2y^2\!+(2-x)^2\right]^2\!+y^2(2-x)^2}=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac1{3|2-x|}\sqrt{y^2(x-2)^2\!+\left[2y^2\!+(2-x)^2\right]^2}\;.\end{align}$

Let $x_A$ and $x_D$ be the abscissas of the points $A$ and $D$.

There are two possible cases :

$1)\;\;x_A\leqslant x_D\;\;,$

$2)\;\;x_A>x_D\;.$

In the first case, it results that

$\begin{align}2S&=2S_{AMC}+2S_{ACD}=\dfrac23S_{ABC}+y(x_D-x_A)=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac y3+y(x_D-x_A)=\dfrac y3\big[1+3(x_D-x_A)\big]=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac y3\left[1+\dfrac{2-5x+2x^2+2y^2}{2-x}\right]=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac{2y\left(2-3x+x^2+y^2\right)}{3(2-x)}\,.\end{align}$

By applying the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, we get that

$\begin{align}AB\cdot CD&=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sqrt{y^2(x-2)^2\!+\left[2y^2\!+(2-x)^2\right]^2}}{3|2-x|}\geqslant\\[3pt]&\geqslant\dfrac{\bigg| x\big[y(x-2)\big]+y\!\left[2y^2\!+(2-x)^2\right]\bigg|}{3|2-x|}=\\[3pt]&=\left|\dfrac{2y\left(2-3x+x^2+y^2\right)}{3(2-x)}\right|\geqslant2S\;.\end{align}$

In the second case, it results that

$S=\begin{cases}S_{ADM}\!+\!S_{AMC}<S_{ADC}\!+\!S_{AMC}&\text{if }M\!\not\in\!\triangle ADC\\[3pt]<S_{ADC}<S_{ADC}\!+\!S_{AMC}&\text{if }M\!\in\!\triangle ADC\end{cases}$

Consequently ,

$\begin{align}2S&<2S_{ADC}+2S_{AMC}=y(x_A-x_D)+\dfrac23S_{ABC}=\\[3pt]&=y(x_A-x_D)+\dfrac y3=\dfrac y3\big[3(x_A-x_D)+1\big]=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac y3\left[\dfrac{5x-2-2x^2-2y^2}{2-x}+1\right]=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac{2y\left(2x-x^2-y^2\right)}{3(2-x)}=\dfrac{2y\big[x(2-x)-y^2\big]}{3(2-x)}\,.\end{align}$

Moreover ,

$\begin{align}AB\cdot CD&=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sqrt{y^2(x-2)^2\!+\left[2y^2\!+(2-x)^2\right]^2}}{3|2-x|}=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2\!+y^2}\sqrt{4y^4\!+5y^2(2-x)^2\!+(2-x)^4}}{3|2-x|}>\\[3pt]&>\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2\!+y^2}\sqrt{4y^4\!+4y^2(2-x)^2}}{3|2-x|}=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2\!+(-y)^2}\,\sqrt{4y^2(2-x)^2\!+\left(2y^2\right)^2}}{3|2-x|}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\text{ Cauchy–Schwarz }\\\text{ inequality }}}{\geqslant}\\[3pt]&\geqslant\dfrac{\big|2xy(2-x)-2y^3\big|}{3|2-x|}=\dfrac{\bigg|2y\big[x(2-x)-y^2\big]\bigg|}{3|2-x|}=\\[3pt]&=\left|\dfrac{2y\big[x(2-x)-y^2\big]}{3(2-x)}\right|\geqslant\dfrac{2y\big[x(2-x)-y^2\big]}{3(2-x)}>2S\;.\end{align}$

Hence, in any case we have proved that $\,AB\cdot CD\geqslant2S\,.\\[10pt]$

---

**Addendum :**

Now, we will prove that

if the coordinates of the vertices of the triangle $ABC$ are $\,A(x,y)\,,\,$ where $\,y>0\,,\;$ $B(0,0)\,,\,$ $C(1,0)\,,\;$ then

$AB\cdot CD=2S\iff\begin{cases}x^3+(x+2)y^2-4x^2+4x=0\\[3pt]-2<x<0\end{cases}$

**Proof :**

$AB\cdot CD=2S\;$ implies $\;x_A\leqslant x_D\,,\;$ otherwise it would result $\,AB\cdot CD>2S\;$ (see the second case of the previous proof).

Let $\;a=x\,,\,$ $b=y\,,\,$ $c=y(x-2)\,,\,$ $d=2y^2\!+(2-x)^2\,.$

It results that

$ac+bd=2y\left(2-3x+x^2+y^2\right)\;\;,$

$ad-bc=x^3+(x+2)y^2-4x^2+4x\;\;.$

Moreover, according to the first case of the previous proof,
$AB=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\;,\;$ $CD=\dfrac{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{3|2-x|}\;,\;$ $2S=\dfrac{ab+cd}{3(2-x)}\;.$

From the equalities

$\left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(c^2+d^2\right)=\left(ac+bd\right)^2+\left(ad-bc\right)^2\;\;,$

$AB^2\!\cdot CD^2=4S^2\;\;,$

it follows that

$ad-bc=0\;\;,\;\;$ that is

$x^3+(x+2)y^2-4x^2+4x=0\;\;,\;\;$ which implies

$-2<x<0\;.$

On the other hand

$\begin{cases}x^3+(x+2)y^2-4x^2+4x=0\\[3pt]-2<x<0\end{cases}\quad$ implies

$x_A-x_D=\dfrac{5x-2-2x^2-2y^2}{3(2-x)}<0\;\;,\;\;$ that is ,

$x_A<x_D\quad$ ( first case of the previous proof ).

Let $\;a=x\,,\,$ $b=y\,,\,$ $c=y(x-2)\,,\,$ $d=2y^2\!+(2-x)^2\,.$

According to the first case of the previous proof,
$AB=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\;,\;$ $CD=\dfrac{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{3|2-x|}\;,\;$ $2S=\dfrac{ab+cd}{3(2-x)}\;.$
Actually , $\;CD=\dfrac{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{3(2-x)}\;$ because $\;-2<x<0\;$ implies $\;2-x>0\;.$

Since

$ac+bd=2y\left(2-3x+x^2+y^2\right)>0\;\;,$

$ad-bc=x^3+(x+2)y^2-4x^2+4x=0\;\;$ and

$\left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(c^2+d^2\right)=\left(ac+bd\right)^2+\left(ad-bc\right)^2\;\;,$

it follows that

$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}=ab+cd\;\;,\;\;$ hence ,

$AB\cdot CD=2S\,.$